# Compiling error using llvm clang in iOS (on device,jailbreaken)

Tags: ios, llvm-clang, toolchain

how can I fix this error?:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmZea.jpg

I got this error when compiling a simple c++ file but I don't know why
When I compile this file with iOS 6.1 sdk it works but I want it to work in iOS sdk 8.1
My iPad:ipad 3 wifi
My iOS version:8.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be problem with the architecture. As far as I know Apple hasn't changed Armv7. From what I see, its a linker error, probably caused by libraries not being linked in correctly. Pretty clear when it says: `ignoring nonexistent library`. This type of error could occur if you import a header and fail to link it against the correct library OR if you just straight up include a header for the wrong architecture -_-.

So thats the diagnosis. I guess the rest of the hacking is up to you since no one here has any clue what you have done to the poor iPad.

Comment: Solved it myself about 4 months ago but thanks still:) @MaxKargin